# Mouse busy cursor is lost

Tags: 11.04, unity

After a clean install of 11.04, I don't see the busy indicator of mouse cursor anymore, except first startup. I have to check the harddisk busy light every time (for which I have to look under table, which is annoying). Other cursors are fine.

Any idea how can I fix this weird situation?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe nothing on your system has triggered the "busy" cursor. Some changes that landed in 11.04 (such as the way the kernel handles processes) might make it far less likely for you to see the busy cursor. Personally I only see it on rare occasions.

Comment: that is a shame then. I really feel better when I can see os is busy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in Unity 3D. The solution is to add `StartupNotify=true` under the `[Desktop Entry]` in your `.desktop` file.